# How to reference data with different key in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and need to store a data set. The data set looks like the following

```
id | time | value
01 |   1  |   1
01 |   2  |   0
01 |   3  |   1
01 |   4  |   0
01 |   5  |   1
02 |   1  |   2
02 |   2  |   3
02 |   3  |   7
02 |   4  |   9
02 |   5  |   5
```

I would like to be able to search the data either by `id` or by `time`, i.e.

```
GetValueByID(data, '01')
# id | time | value
# 01 |   1  |   1
# 01 |   2  |   0
# 01 |   3  |   1
# 01 |   4  |   0
# 01 |   5  |   1

GetValueByID(data, '2')
# id | time | value
# 01 |   2  |   0
# 02 |   2  |   3
```

What would be the most memory efficient way of doing this?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you supposed to allow duplicate id's, if so, what is the rule for handling which value should be returned on lookup, should it be a set?

Comment: boost::multiindex was made just for this.  https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.multiindex http://david-grs.github.io/why_boost_multi_index_container-part1/ http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The most *memory* efficient method is to create a class with ID, Time and Value members, then use a `std::vector` of the class.

For run-time efficiency, you want to create an *index table* or `std::map` containing the search key field and the index of the item in the vector.  Create one map for ID and another for the Time field.  This is a common approach with database tables.

**Edit 1: Duplicate keys**
You use `std::map` if the key fields are unique.  Use an unordered map when keys are not unique.

Comment: Just a note: std::map becomes more efficient only when the array reaches a certain size.  With the small data sets presented std::vector would probably end up being be more efficient than std::map.